# Cannot perform a cyclic copy

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder `c:\data\_backup`.
I want to copy all of the files that are in `data` folder to `_backup`, then I created a script `run.cmd` in the folder `_backup` but I have no success, because it says:

> ```
> Can not perform a cyclic copy
> 0 File (s) copied
> Press any key to continue. . .
> ```

I use the following script:

```
cd..
xcopy ".\*" "%cd%\_backup\%date:~-4,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%" /s /i /y
pause
```

Comment: i use this script not success too..

Comment: cd..
xcopy "*.*" "%cd%\_backup\%date:~-4,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%" /s /e /i /y
pause

Comment: You are copying from a folder that contains the target folder and asking for a recursive copy (`/s`). This means the target folder is included in the source selection, something not allowed by `xcopy`. Change folder locations to avoid the source/target collision or, if not needed, remove the `/s` request.

Comment: MC ND.
i use following this script success.
- cd..
- echo %cd%
- pause
xcopy "*.*" "%cd%\_backup\%date:~-4,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%\" /y
pause
but only file. in "folder data" there are some folders it's cannot copy to "folder _backup"..

Comment: @bede, place the `_backup` folder out of the source folder. Or use `robocopy` and use the `/xd` switch to exclude the `_backup` folder

Comment: To use `xcopy`, create a file `exclude.txt` with the content `\_backup\ `, then add the option `/EXCLUDE:exclude.txt` to the `xcopy` command line...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use robocopy to copy the files like mael' said above, with something like

```
set /P filea=What is the file you want to copy?
set /P fileb=Where do you want the file?
robocopy filea fileb
echo Copy done!
pause
```

If you want individual lines, you can do something like this

```
set /P filea=What is the file you want to copy?
set /P fileb=Where do you want the file?
%save%< %filea% (
set /p line1=
set /p line2=
set /p savedate=
)
set savedate=%DATE:~-4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%%TIME%
(
echo %line1%
echo %line2%
echo %savedate%
) > %fileb%
echo Copy done!
```

To get individual lines, you'd need to put the same amount of `echo`s that the file has in the first part, and only the lines you want in the second.

Answer (score -2):

If you're only trying to copy files as your question states, `robocopy` will accomplish this without any options:

```
robocopy "c:\data" "c:\data\_backup"
```

By default `robocopy` only copies files, and there are plenty of options you can use if you're trying to accomplish other things or handle errors.